# transition ease for translate only smooth the first time on Iphone

Tags: jquery, ios, css

This is a basic mobile slide in/slide out menu.

I'm finding it difficult to debug , but basically my issue is that when I press the menu button the menu opens smoothly, and press it again and it closes smoothly. However when I press it again (for the third time) it does **not** open smoothly , it just appears. However it still carries on with closing smoothly.

I want it to open and close smoothly all the time. I cannot figure out the cause but Im thinking its something to do with the position it's reaching when it closes. Almost as if it's not the same position it was when the page loaded.

**JS**

```
$('.mobile-menu').click( function(){
    $(this).next().toggleClass('open');

});
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="top-links">

        <div class="mobile-menu"> <span></span><span></span><span></span><div>Menu</div></div>
        <ul class="nav-menu">
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="">account</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Help</a></li>


        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#top-links {
    margin-right: 2.5%;
    width: 140px;
}

.nav-menu {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../image/grey-bg.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0;
    padding-bottom: 38px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 90%;
    padding-left:10%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    -o-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform .5s ease;
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .5s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
    height:240px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;

}

.nav-menu.open {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
    -o-transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%);
    transition: transform .5s ease;
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform .5s ease;

}


.nav-menu::after {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.27);
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    height: 90px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom:-73px;
    transform: rotate(-1deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-1deg) ;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-1deg) ;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-1deg) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var menuIcon =  $('.mobile-menu')[0]; //or just give your menu icon a id   
var nav = $('.nav-menu')[0];    
$(menuIcon).click( function(){
    $(nav).toggleClass('open');  
});
```